# Programmatically add a managed metadata term store and set BCS permissions

Tags: managed-metadata

I would like all my Lists, MMS's, WebParts, External Content types to be deployed to SharePoint without any need to insert anything manual.

I figured out how to make lists but i can not find any way to deploy a MMS to a SharePoint site. Also deploying the WSP files of the webparts is failing...

After i deployed all this i also need to set permissions to the deployed Content Type.
Anybody got any example of above problems?

Answer (score 1):

Ben Robb has an article on [Manipulating the Terms Store through Powershell](http://sharepointtales.wordpress.com/2010/05/06/manipulating-the-terms-store-through-powershell/) as one way of automating the deployment of MMS data.

Can you give us more information on what is failing with the webparts - using a WSP is the recommended way of deploying the other SharePoint artefacts.

Comment: I just managed to deploy wsp files using PS.
So ill check ur link about the terms store. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provide a sample on how to manipulate the ACLs of MetaDataObjects (Including Entities) in the BCS.

[Code Snippet: Add an Access Control Entry to a MetadataObject Using the Administration Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff464426.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote some code that had to work with the term store programmatically:

http://charliedigital.com/2010/10/27/updating-sharepoint-taxonomy-fields/

Some more info here:

http://www.sharepoint4developers.net/en-nz/post/setting-taxonomy-field-values.aspx

Basically, you need to reference the Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy DLL and you should have access to all of the classes and services in there.  This should allow you to build up your term store programmatically.

I'd recommend doing it with an input structure like an XML file or something so that it's not *entirely* hardcoded...